# Как пригласить бота на другой дискорд сервер?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

вопрос следующий - Как мне пригласить своего бота написанного на discord.py на discord сервер, на котором у меня нет прав администратора ?

**Зачем мне это надо ?**

Есть дискорд сервер, с которого мне через бота надо получать информацию о сообщениях. Есть ли возможность так сделать ?

Если так не получиться, есть ли возможность сделать client бота, который будет делать то же самое

**Что мне конкретно надо получать ?**

Мне надо по ID сообщения, получить людей которые ставят туда реакции, и получать это на постоянной основе. Увы сервер не мой и попросить Владельца дать мне доступ для приглашения бота - никак не получится.

Comment: `есть ли возможность сделать client бота` self-боты запрещены пользовательским соглашением Дискорда.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, такое сделать **никак** нельзя!

Только если сам создатель или администратор, у которого есть нужные права, не пригласят его на сервер.